# Discrepancy in Ticket Counts and Missing Data After Merging Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I'm encountering an issue with a function that merges two dataframes, `DF_dbt` (containing ITS & Leap transactions) and AVL data (`DF_vehtrips`, `DF_vehstops`, `DF_nompts_nompatpts`). After merging, I am observing discrepancies in ticket counts on 24-hour routes, duplicates, and missing data. Here's an overview of the problem:

#### Problem:

1. **Dropped Tickets on 24-Hour Routes**: The merged dataframe (`DF_db`) shows a significant drop in ticket counts compared to the original ITS & Leap transactions (`DF_dbt`) for 24-hour routes. For example:

   - `DF_dbt[DF_dbt['Route Variant']=='1'].shape[0]`: 2775
   - `DF_db[DF_db['Route Variant']=='1'].shape[0]`: 1932
2. **Duplicates**: There are instances of duplicated tickets in the merged dataframe (`DF_db`).
3. **Missing Data**: Some tickets seem to have missing information after the merge.

#### Code:

Here's the `merge_leap_its_avl` function I'm using:

```
    '''
    This function merges the unified ITS & Leap transactions dataframe with the AVL data. It uses the columns 'line_id', 
    'stop_number' and 'Fleet ID' in the unified dataframe to map it to the right vehicle trips on that date.

    Input:
    df --> The unified dataframe for the ITS and Leap transactions
    avl --> Dictionary containing AVL dataframes (DF_vehtrips, DF_vehstops, DF_nompts_nompatpts)
    
    Output:
    df --> The unified dataframe after being unified with the AVL data
    '''

    # Get AVL dataframes
    DF_vehtrips = avl['DF_vehtrips']
    DF_vehstops = avl['DF_vehstops']
    DF_nompts_nompatpts = avl['DF_nompts_nompatpts']

    # Filter out ITS/Leap transactions with missing AVL vehicles
    its_vehs = df["Fleet_Id"].unique()
    avl_vehs = DF_vehtrips["fleet_id"].unique()
    missing_veh = [i for i in its_vehs if i not in avl_vehs]
    df = df[~df["Fleet_Id"].isin(missing_veh)]

    # Merge with DF_vehtrips
    df = df.merge(DF_vehtrips[['event_no',  'line_id', 'trip_code', 'pattern_id',  
                               'fleet_id', 'act_dep_time_clean', 'nom_dep_time']],
                  left_on='Fleet_Id', right_on='fleet_id', how='inner')

    # Filter out ITS/Leap transactions where ticket time is close to departure time
    df = df[(df['ticket_tm'] + timedelta(minutes=3)) > df['act_dep_time_clean']]

    # Group by ObjectId to find last stop time
    df_t = df.groupby(['ObjectId'])['act_dep_time_clean'].max().reset_index() 
    df = df.merge(df_t, on=['ObjectId', 'act_dep_time_clean'], how='inner')

    # Separate rows where stop_number is 0
    df_t = df[df.stop_number == 0]
    df = df[df.stop_number > 0]

    # Drop unnecessary columns
    df_t.drop(columns=['act_dep_time_clean', 'stop_number'], inplace=True)
    
    # Merge with DF_vehstops
    df_t = df_t.merge(DF_vehstops[['event_no_trip', 'act_dep_time_clean', 'stop_number']],
                      left_on='event_no', right_on='event_no_trip', how='inner')
    
    # Filter out rows based on ticket time and stop_number
    df_t = df_t[(df_t['ticket_tm'] <= (df_t['act_dep_time_clean'] + timedelta(seconds=45))) &
                (df_t.stop_number.notna())]

    # Group by ObjectId to find min stop time
    df_tn = df_t.groupby(['ObjectId'])['act_dep_time_clean'].min().reset_index()
    df_t = df_t.merge(df_tn, on=['ObjectId', 'act_dep_time_clean'], how='inner')
    df_t.drop(columns=['act_dep_time_clean'], inplace=True)

    # Merge with DF_vehtrips to combine new rows
    df_t = df_t.merge(DF_vehtrips[['event_no', 'act_dep_time_clean']], on='event_no', how='inner')

    # Append new rows to original dataframe
    df = df.append(df_t[df.columns])

    # Print info about merged data
    print("* Merged with AVL vehicles trips: Customers Transactions dataset ", df.shape, " *\n")

    # Filter out rows with missing pattern_id or stop_number
    df = df[(df.pattern_id.notna()) & (df['stop_number'] > 0)]
    df = df.astype({'line_id': int, 'stop_number': int})

    # Merge with DF_nompts_nompatpts
    df = pd.merge(df, DF_nompts_nompatpts,
                  left_on=['pattern_id', 'stop_number', 'line_id'],
                  right_on=['pattern_id', 'stop_number', 'line_id'], how='left', suffixes=('', '_nom'))
    
    # Print info about merged data
    print("* Merged with Nom Patterns Points: Customers Transactions dataset ", df.shape, " *\n")

    # Fix last stop index
    DF_patterns_last_stop_index = DF_nompts_nompatpts.groupby(['pattern_id'])['stop_index_no'].max().reset_index()
    df = newUnify.fix_last_stop_index(df, DF_vehtrips, DF_nompts_nompatpts, DF_patterns_last_stop_index)

    # Print info about fixed data
    print("* Fix for the last stop index Tag-ons: Customers Transactions dataset ", df.shape, " *\n")

    return df
```

#### Expected Outcome:

- I expect the number of tickets for 24-hour routes to be closer between `DF_dbt` and `DF_db`.
- I want to address the issue of duplicates and missing data in the merged dataframe.

#### What I've Tried:

1. Filtering out ITS/Leap transactions with missing AVL vehicles.
2. Merging with `DF_vehtrips` based on certain columns.
3. Filtering rows based on ticket time and stop number.
4. Grouping by `ObjectId` to find min/max stop times.
5. Merging with `DF_vehstops` and `DF_nompts_nompatpts`.
6. Fixing last stop index.

#### Questions:

1. Why am I seeing a drop in ticket counts for 24-hour routes after the merge?
2. How can I handle duplicates and missing data during the merge process?

I would appreciate any insights, suggestions, or corrections to the `merge_leap_its_avl` function to resolve these issues. Thank you!

Comment: It's hard to say without the data. You'll have to debug this line by line and see where exactly the data is being dropped or duplicated. If you pinpoint this and still can't understand it, you can create a reproducible example with which SO users will be happy to help you. For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples